# If $E = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: \sin(\frac1{x}) = 1\}$ then $l = 0$ is a limit point of E

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

If $E = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1\}$, then $l = 0$ is a limit point of $E$.

I have a proof here but I don't quite understand a few points, I hope someone can explain it a bit : )

To prove that $l = 0$ is a limit point, we need to show for any $\delta > 0 $, there exists $x \in E $ such that $ 0 < |x-0| < \delta $,

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1 \quad \text{implies}  \quad x = \frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi}. $$

If $k = \max \left(1, \left\lceil \frac{1}{\delta} - \frac{1}{2} \right\rceil \right)$ where $\delta > 0 $, then $0 < \left|\frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi} - 0 \right| < \delta $ so $\exists x \in E$ s.t. $0 < |x-0| < \delta$.

So questions are here,

> 1. Why max function is used here? and why $1$ is chosen?
> 2. Why the ceiling is used for $\left\lceil \frac{1}{\delta} - \frac{1}{2} \right\rceil$?

Comment: because $k$ has to be an integer

Comment: and so why 1 is used in max function?

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way to prove that $0$ is a limit point is to exhibit a sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$ such that $x_n\to0$.

Once this point is clear, I am sure you have an idea about what such a sequence $(x_n)$ could be...

Answer (score 2):

$x_{n}:=1/((4n+1)\pi/2)$ gives you a sequence $x_{n} \in E \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=0$.

Comment: $\sin((2n+1)\pi/2)=(-1)^n$. So $4n+1$ will work better.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll edit